# How to get grand total without tax in Magento2 shopping cart page?

Tags: tax, shopping-cart, tax-calculation

Hi please help me on this it's little urgent thanks in advance,

How to get grand total without tax in **Magento2 shopping cart** page

let me explain it,
i have added product in backend with price : 10 rs ( inclusive of tax 10 % manually calculated from my side ) ,
tax class : 10% tax 
so tax is 1rs for that product,
now i need in checkout page & in cart page should look like ;

Subtotal : 10 rs

### tax ( 10% ) : 1rs

Grand total : 10 Rs

pls help me in th

Comment: You can include or exclude the tax into your grand total but I think you can't completely eliminate the Tax in Magento 2

Comment: thx for reply MR.Abhishek , if you dnt mine can you  plese let me where i need to change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to show the tax at your frontend just go to your admin & traverse to the below location

```
admin > Stores > Configurations > Sates > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings
```

Set `Display Prices` to **Including Tax**  & `Display Subtotal` to **Including Tax** like the given Image

[image]

& save it Then see the frontend changes it will not show the tax there

[image]

Here in the image the actual product price is **$18.86** but it is showing it as **$19.99** including tax on the **shopping cart** page.

> Note: Make sure when you do this changes
>
> - don't enter the price into the product listing including tax just put the price there excluding tax it will show the tax as per your requirement.
> - your cache is set to disabled or run the below command from your magento root
>
>   php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: thanks for reply actually i have a product with tax(i will upload in my admin panel it self while adding product) but just i need to show to clients how much tax in shopping cart page that's it

Comment: So for that you need to create the shipping tax rate it has no any relation with the product tax rate

Comment: if you dnt mine pls let me how to do  iam trying from last 2 days pls help me on this thanks in advance

Comment: first make me clear what you want exactly would be better if you add some pictorial explanation in your question, & be clear that you want to show the tax on the shopping cart or not

Comment: Ok ., let me explain it 

i have added product in backend with price : 10 rs ( inclusive of tax 10 % manually calculated from my side )  , tax class : 10% tax so tax is 1rs 

now i need in checkout page & in cart page should look like ;
Subtotal : 10 rs
tax ( 10% ) : 1rs 
--------------------------
Grand total : 10 Rs

pls help me in this

Comment: See my updated answer @ChalaChalapathi

Comment: yes i need tax in shoping cart page and checkout page but it should not add to total price means (grand total) thats it